# Virtual box - How to add disks and move var, opt and home to them?

Tags: virtualbox, mount, centos5

I created a CentOS 5.6 Guest OS Virtual Machine.
I made the first disk 10GB, I am rapidly outgrowing it.

It was suggested that I make disks for my `/var`, `/opt` and `/home` directories and move them so I can better manage the disks for backing up and what not.

This sounds like a good idea.

I know how to create the disks in Virtual Box. I have dug around Google and the internet in general and all my attempts at doing this have failed. Snapshots are awesome!

I can get the drives `fdisk`ed, and I have had limited success mounting them to `/mnt/var`, `/mnt/home` and `/mnt/opt`, but even in single user mode ( `init 1` ) I can't get the entire contents of the directories to move over, and then the machine won't reboot correctly.

```
cd /var
cp * -ax /mnt/var
```

The `/var` directory in particular is not wanting to move everything to the new location.

**How do I format, mount and move the `/var`, `/opt` and `/home` to my new disks?**

Answer (score 1):

The problem *probably* is that the filesystem continuosly change by writes from the OS and various daemons.

It's expecially true for /var (less likely for /home or /opt if in single user mode).

The easiest way IMHO is to boot the VM with a Linux Live CD of some kind (you can download an `.iso` and mount it as CDROM drive, then set it as first device to boot). Then you can mount your old and new disks and make the copies you need.

**Don't delete anything**.

When done with copying you should modify `/mount_point/etc/fstab` (the old disk) with the new values for `/var`, `/opt` and `/home` (possibly using UUIDs) and reboot.

Then, **only if everything went ok**, you should re-boot the Live CD, mount the old disk, and delete the old data to make room.